# Why does Flexbox not respect width when nested?

Tags: css, flexbox

`Flexbox` doens't respect the width I provide, but it respects the width from the child elements. Could anyone explain why?

I've setup an example how the html looks like, All unnecessary code is stripped. But the structure is basically build when using JS components (`vue` which in this case is not really of interest)

```
<div class="row container">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="row container">
      <div class="col col1">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="content">test1</div>
          <div class="content">test2</div>
          <div class="content">test3</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col col2">test2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.row {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%
}

.container {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.content {
  min-width: 300px;
}

.col1 {
  background-color: lightblue;
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow-x: auto;
  flex-shrink: 1;
}

.col2 {
  background-color: salmon;
  min-width: 300px;
 }
```

Here is also a link to JS fiddle to reproduce: https://codepen.io/reijnemans/pen/WNNKXGp

**Expected result**: `.container` has a width of 100%; and `.col1` should have a scroll-bar to scroll over all `.content` items. The structure of the html could not be changed regarding `flexbox`

JS fiddle first example has the wrong example, second example workt fine but has one layer less of `flexbox`, which is unfortunately not possible in my case. (Second example has the same structure only without the outer row and col)

Comment: `min-width: 0;` to col element

Comment: Don't know how I missed that, thx a lot.